# onClick of Tab component is not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, onclick, material-ui

I am using the Tab component of the material-ui library for react.

I am trying to achieve a hackery solution for a problem I am facing but my onClick listener does not seem to be triggered.

Example of one of my tabs:

```
<Tab key={4} style={styles.tabstyles} onClick={localStorage.setItem('pageNumber', 3)} />
```

However pageNumber in local storage is not changed when I click on this tab.

Alternatively I've tried putting the onClick code into a separate reusable function, but this are only triggered when the web app boots up and there is subsequently no change to pageNumber upon clicking on either tabs.

It may seem for this issue I can use react-router, but that's not what I want. I want to know how to change local storage upon clicking a tab.

Thanks in advance

---

pageNumber not changing (always set to 3):

```
<Tabs style={style.tabstyle}>
   <Tab key={3} style={styles.tabstyles} onClick={this.setPageNumber(2)} />
   <Tab key={4} style={styles.tabstyles} onClick={this.setPageNumber(3)} />
</Tabs>
```

And my function within this component:

```
setPageNumber(no) {
  localStorage.setItem('pageNumber',no);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick` will not fire on `Tab` you need to use onChange to `Tabs` also instead of `key` attribute use `value`

```
 <Tabs style={style.tabstyle} onChange={this.setPageNumber} value={this.state.checked} >
            <Tab value={3} style={styles.tabstyles}   />
            <Tab value={4} style={styles.tabstyles} />
 </Tabs>
```

`setPageNumber` function

```
setPageNumber(no){
  localStorage.setItem('pageNumber', no);
  console.log(no, 'checked')
}
```

> You need to bind `setPageNumber` function in your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    checked: null,
  }
  this.setPageNumber = this.setPageNumber.bind(this);
}
```

[image: Edit 6w8817kpjw]